# How to get method which returns the String version of the Fraction in the form of “numerator / denominator” of fraction

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fractioncal;

import static java.lang.Integer.sum;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author abdallah
 */
public class FractionCal {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Fraction Calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter first fraction");
        String firstfraction = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second fraction");
        String secondfraction = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Processing "+firstfraction+","+secondfraction);

        String frac0 = firstfraction.substring(0,1);
        String frac1 = firstfraction.substring(2,3);

        int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(frac0);
        int denominator1 = Integer.parseInt(frac1);

        String frac2 = secondfraction.substring(0,1);
        String frac3 = secondfraction.substring(2,3);
        int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(frac2);
        int denominator2 = Integer.parseInt(frac3);
        int sum = getAdd(numerator1, numerator2,denominator1,denominator2,firstfraction);

        System.out.println("Sum ="+sum);

    }
    public static int getAdd(int numerator1, int numerator2,int denominator1, int denominator2,String firstfraction ){

        int numer = (numerator1 * denominator2) + (denominator1 * numerator2);
        int deno = (denominator1*denominator2);                 

        return sum(numer,deno);
    }   
}
```

Comment: but why are you adding the numerator to the denominator??????

Comment: This is my fisrt part I'm going an addition after i have to do substr, multipl, and quotient. My output is wrong show the format of fraction

Comment: For something like this, because a fraction consists of two integer numbers, you really need a `Fraction` class. Have you learned about writing your own class with fields yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getAdd()` method should be like this:

```
public static String getAdd(int numerator1, int numerator2, int denominator1, int denominator2) {

    int numer = (numerator1 * denominator2) + (denominator1 * numerator2);
    int deno = (denominator1 * denominator2);

    return numer + "/" + deno;
}
```

For input:

```
1/3 and 2/4
```

Output:

```
Sum =10/12
```

Comment: @Abdallah please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Abdallah then you can **upvote** and **accept** this answer. You can find how to do it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: public static int wholeNumber(int a, int b) {
        int Numerator =0;
        int Denominator = 0;
     a = Math.abs(Numerator / Denominator);
     b = Numerator % Denominator;
                   
              return wholeNumber(b, a%b);

Comment: And now is it ok, I have a question if I want to print the whole number how I have to do

Comment: @Abdallah what do you want to do in this `wholeNumber` method? Can you explain what would be the input and what would be the expected output?

Comment: I was looking to create a method of calculating the whole number of fraction which whole number of resultat sum. "sum = 0.83 10/12"

Comment: @Abdallah It's very easy. Check this: https://ideone.com/i25MzA